# Batik Canvas' getUpdateManager returns null

Tags: java, swing, batik

When using Batik to get the **`UpdateManager`** from **`JSVGCanvas`**, it returns **`null`**.

```
public void init() {
    canvas = new JSVGCanvas(null, true, false);
    canvas.setDocumentState(JSVGCanvas.ALWAYS_DYNAMIC);
}

public void paint(final DomainObject domainObject) {
    UpdateManager updateManager = canvas.getUpdateManager();
    RunnableQueue runnableQueue = updateManager.getUpdateRunnableQueue();
    runnableQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Document operations here
        }
    });
}
```

How can this error be managed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method for painting had to be splitted in two parts being one the registering of a `GVTTreeRendererListener` to the `JSVGCanvas` object. Once the rendering is completed this listener invokes the method that does the actual painting work, by that time the UpdateManager object is present in the canvas.

```
public void init() {
    canvas = new JSVGCanvas(null, true, false);
    canvas.setDocumentState(JSVGCanvas.ALWAYS_DYNAMIC);
}

public void paint(final DomainObject domainObject) {
    canvas.addGVTTreeRendererListener(new GVTTreeRendererAdapter() {
        public void gvtRenderingCompleted(GVTTreeRendererEvent e) {
            renderComplete(domainObject);
        }
    });
}

public void renderComplete(DomainObject domainObject) {
    UpdateManager updateManager = canvas.getUpdateManager();
    RunnableQueue runnableQueue = updateManager.getUpdateRunnableQueue();
    runnableQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Document operations here
        }
    });
}
```

DISCLAIMER:
The answer was found in this Batik forum and I decided to document it here as a more useful resource http://batik.2283329.n4.nabble.com/UpdateManager-is-Null-td2974717.html